# Glassmapper issue with Sitecore 9.3 causing intermittent 500 error on pages

Tags: glass-mapper

We are experiencing below issue in few of our CD site urls. We tried below fixes, but no luck.

Index rebuild
Restarting CD instance
Validated the memory and CPU load on CD and Redis which looks fine
If anyone has come across this issue please share your inputs.

Sitecore version - Sitecore 9.3

Glassmapper version - 5.8.173.0

Service has been disposed, cannot create object.

[MapperException: Service has been disposed, cannot create object]
Glass.Mapper.AbstractService.InstantiateObject(AbstractTypeCreationContext abstractTypeCreationContext) in D:\a\Glass.Mapper\Glass.Mapper\Source\Glass.Mapper\AbstractService.cs:126
Glass.Mapper.Sc.SitecoreService.RunCreateType(Item item, GetOptions options, Dictionary`2 parameters) in D:\a\Glass.Mapper\Glass.Mapper\Source\Glass.Mapper.Sc\SitecoreService.cs:349 Glass.Mapper.Sc.SitecoreService.GetItem(GetItemOptions options) in D:\a\Glass.Mapper\Glass.Mapper\Source\Glass.Mapper.Sc\SitecoreService.cs:338 Glass.Mapper.Sc.DataMappers.SitecoreSelfMapper.MapToProperty(AbstractDataMappingContext mappingContext) in D:\a\Glass.Mapper\Glass.Mapper\Source\Glass.Mapper.Sc\DataMappers\SitecoreSelfMapper.cs:34 Glass.Mapper.Pipelines.ObjectConstruction.Tasks.CreateInterface.InterfacePropertyInterceptor.LoadValue(AbstractPropertyConfiguration propertyConfiguration) in D:\a\Glass.Mapper\Glass.Mapper\Source\Glass.Mapper\Pipelines\ObjectConstruction\Tasks\CreateInterface\InterfacePropertyInterceptor.cs:121 Glass.Mapper.Pipelines.ObjectConstruction.Tasks.CreateInterface.InterfacePropertyInterceptor.Intercept(IInvocation invocation) in D:\a\Glass.Mapper\Glass.Mapper\Source\Glass.Mapper\Pipelines\ObjectConstruction\Tasks\CreateInterface\InterfacePropertyInterceptor.cs:85 Castle.DynamicProxy.AbstractInvocation.Proceed() +449 Castle.Proxies.IProductVmProxy.get_MetaData() +138 xxxxx.Logic.Pipelines.Metadata.GetProductMetadata.Process(GetPageMetadataArgs args) +900 (Object , Object ) +45 Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args) +490 Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain, Boolean failIfNotExists) +236 Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain) +23 xxxxxx.Logic.Services.Metadata.MetadataService.Get(Item item) +1906 xxxxxx.Web.Areas.Metadata.Controllers.MetaDataController.MetaData() +108 lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] ) +87 System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters) +35
System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass24_0.b__0() +80
System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodFilter(IActionFilter filter, ActionExecutingContext preContext, Func`1 continuation) +466 System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodFilter(IActionFilter filter, ActionExecutingContext preContext, Func`1 continuation) +466
System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeAction(ControllerContext controllerContext, String actionName) +521

We also found in Azure logs that it is giving below error as well. But we don’t see any memory/cpu alerts on CD

[PhysicalMemoryProtection] Snapshot (518.03 MB), in extreme cases, could make the available machine physical memory 1011.77 MB) be less than 15% of total physical memory (4.00 GB).

As a result we are seeing intermittent errors on pages across the site. Kindly help and let us know your thoughts/suggestions on same on same.

Regards,

Christopher

Comment: What is full spec of machine?

Comment: Have you validated that in your custom code methods such as xxxxxx.Logic.Services.Metadata.MetadataService.Get(Item item) +1906 that you are not improperly disposing of the Sitecore service too early? If you are using a GlassMapper Sitecore service to query for a Glass item, and that item is used outside of the using statement, the Sitecore service may be disposed of too early. Is there much business logic related to these Glass items outside of any relevant using statements in your custom code methods? Do you see these errors on other custom components that you've built utilizing GlassMapper,